# Is Server Fault the appropriate website to ask about system design questions?

Tags: discussion, design, asking-questions

Note: This is a follow-up question to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290723/is-stack-overflow-the-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-system-design-questions?noredirect=1#comment179004_290723) one.

I'm planning to practice some system design questions asked during tech interviews, and I'd like to get reviews/opinions on how I'd design some systems from the ServerFault/StackExchange community if I can.

Can I post these questions on Server Fault, or would some other StackExchange site be more appropriate for this?

Comment: What is it you're trying to design?

Comment: Is the goal to help you get a job?  Regardless of it isn't an actual problem you are facing then it has to fall into the good subjective rule which would be difficult from what you've described so far.

Comment: I quite like System Design questions.  I often use them as a springboard for blogposts.

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, this sounds to me like something that might be closed as a duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)  Depending on how you define "system design," of course.  I'm assuming this is a server system because you're on Server Fault, and you'd be talking about server hardware and operating systems and the like (possibly to support an application).  Am I assuming correctly?

If the system is unix/linux, [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) might be a good choice.

If the system runs databases, [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) might be a good choice.

If the systems are desktops, [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) might be a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

My gut feeling is that system design questions are not off-topic *per se* - they're a class of best-practice questions, which I recall a while back we decided to be more tolerant of.

But it's still perfectly possible to write a system design question that's off-topic for other reasons.  For example, in my opinion:

- *What's the best way to design an online auction site* - too broad
- *What's the best design for a home media server* - not about managing information technology systems in a business environment
- *What's the best answer to this interview question* - [this is a hypothetical, not a concrete, issue](https://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask)

So, if you actually have a real system to design, and you've done your homework and narrowed things down to two or three options, but genuinely can't decide which one's best, then my personal feeling is that there might well be an interesting, on-topic question there.  I can't speak for the community, though.

Comment: So, in essence - it's possible to write a systems design question which would be on-topic, but most of the questions we see aren't?

Comment: I'd hesitate to give a definitive answer without checking the data, but that's my gut feeling, yes.

Comment: Now I think about it, that pretty much goes for all topics on the site...

Comment: [You might say that; I couldn't possibly comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Urquhart).